# <details><summary> balise in flexdashboard don't work

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am building a flexdashboard with R:

```
---
title: Application
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: 'scroll'
    fig_mobile: TRUE
    self_contained: TRUE
    theme: 'cerulean'
    social: menu
    resize_reload: TRUE
---

## Column {data-width="450"}

## Column {data-width="550"}
### Title
<details><summary>Show/Hide</summary>text to show/hide</details>
```

The result is surprising, R display the element as expected:
[image]

But when I try to display my dashboard with browser, it doesn't work as expected.
[image]

Is it a browser problem (I tried with google chrome and Microsoft Edge) or a flexdashboard issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening, but tweaking with the inspect option of google chrome browser, it seems to work if we set `display: revert` in `summary` tag.

````
---
title: Application
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: 'scroll'
    fig_mobile: TRUE
    self_contained: TRUE
    theme: 'cerulean'
    social: menu
    resize_reload: TRUE
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
summary {
  display: revert;  
}
```

## Column {data-width="450"}

## Column {data-width="550"}
### Title
<details><summary>Show/Hide</summary>text to show/hide</details>
````

---

[image: detail summary workaround for flexdashboard]

---

Comment: work perfect with this css command, thanks @shafee